# How can I test whether an element is in a list using identity instead of equality?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, I can test whether an element is in a list like so:

```
elem = 56
long_list = ["foo", "bar", asdf, 56, False]
print(elem in long_list) # "True"
```

This is equivalent to:

```
elem = 56
long_list = ["foo", "bar", asdf, 56, False]

result = False
for candidate in long_list:
    if elem == candidate:
        result = True
        break
print(result) # "True"
```

Notice `elem == candidate`, which tests for **equality**.

What I want to do is test for **identity** using `elem is candidate` instead. What is the easiest way to do this in Python?

I tried Google, but the words "is" and "in" are unfortunately too common. I also tried

```
print(elem is in long_list)
```

but this gave me a syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

Use `any` with a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
any(elem is candidate for candidate in long_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but if an object doesn't implement `__eq__`, `in` and `==` default to identity comparison, which is what you want.

```
class Foo:
    pass

a = Foo()
b = Foo()
c = Foo()

print (a in [a,b]) # True 
print (c in [a,b]) # False
```

Comment: I do want to use `is` instead of `==`, but the reason is more complicated than given here. I said "I am comparing objects which do not implement `__eq__`" to keep things simple, but it looks like I have been found out ;) I've removed the statement since it is evidently a red herring.

Comment: What is your actual use case? I don't think I've ever needed this.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements being compared implement `__eq__` in terms of `is`, you can simply use `elem in long_list` and it will be invoked for you automatically. So this should work with your objects:

```
def __eq__(self, x):
    return self is x
```

To keep things simple, here's a little demo that overloads equality to be `str.startswith` (of the second operand) instead of identity.

```
>>> class permissive(str):
        def __eq__(self, x):
            return self.startswith(x)

>>> mylist = map(permissive, [ "hip", "hop" ])
>>> "hi" in mylist
True
```

Of course you'll get the same super-strict behavior when comparing your objects for equality in other contexts. If your goal is just to find a specific object in a list, perhaps you should define `__hash__` instead and store them in a dictionary?